# Keeping models consistent across 2 collections when setting attributes and cloning in Backbone?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I need to keep the models used in 2 collections `Movies` and `Watchlist` the same at all times, both collections use the same model but I need to clone models and add them to `Watchlist` as well as set attributes `watchlist: true/false` depending if added or removed. My problem is that when I clone and log out my 2 collections the models `watchlist` attributes don't match up. Can anyone advise how to resolve this?

A snippet of my add and remove methods

```
onWatchlistAdd: function(model) {
    console.log('AppView::onWatchlistAdd', model);

    model.set('watchlist', true);

    var clonedFilm = model.clone();

    dataStore.watchlist.add(clonedFilm);

    clonedFilm.save();

    console.info(dataStore.watchlist);
},

onWatchlistRemove: function(model) {
    console.log('AppView::onWatchlistRemove', model);

    model.set('watchlist', false);

    console.log(dataStore.watchlist.toJSON()); //model 1 = watchlist:true
    console.log(dataStore.movies.toJSON()); // model 1 = watchlist:false

    dataStore.watchlist.remove(model);

    model.destroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would handle it like this: (a combination of monitoring and view events.)

http://jsfiddle.net/gLxpb9dq/

```
var movies = new Backbone.Collection();
var watchlist = new (Backbone.Collection.extend({
    initialize: function(models, options) {
        // watchlist monitors for changes on the movie collection
        // and just proxy the event to its self
        this.listenTo(options.monitor, 'destroy', this.destroy);
    }
}))(null, {monitor: movies}); 

// test data
movies.add({title: 'Die Hard'});
movies.add({title: 'Die Hard 2'});
movies.add({title: 'Die Hard 3'});
movies.add({title: 'Die Hard 4'});

var MovieItem = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'label',
    template: _.template('<input type="checkbox"><%=title%><input class="delete" value="x" type="button"><br>'),
    events: {
        'click .delete': 'delete',
        'click': 'toggle'
    },
    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    },
    delete: function() {
        // HANDLE THIS BETTER!!!! THIS IS NOT NOT NOT NOT GOOD!!!! (i just didnt want to google it)
        this.model.destroy();
        this.el.remove();
        console.log(watchlist.pluck('title'))
        return false;
    },
    toggle: _.debounce(function(event) {
        // easy, if its there, delete it, if not add it
        if(watchlist.get(this.model)) {
            watchlist.remove(this.model);
        } else {
            watchlist.add(this.model)
        }
        console.log(watchlist.pluck('title'))
    }, 100)
});

new (Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {
        this.$el = $('body');
        this.el = this.$el[0];
        this.render();
    },
    render: function() {
        var el = this.$el.html('');
        _.each(this.collection.models, function(movie) {
            el.append((new MovieItem({model: movie})).el)
        });
        return this;
    }
}))({collection: movies});
```